# Flutter, How to solve "RenderBox was not laid out: ... NEEDS-PAINT"

Tags: flutter, widget

I am trying to show a list using `GridView.builder` and showing one child in each row... Here is the part of the code:

```
SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Header(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Expanded(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Konten())),

          ],
        ),
      )
```

and code for `Konten()`:

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: GridView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 1,
            crossAxisSpacing: 16,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            childAspectRatio:
                10
            ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(data[index]["API"]),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.amber, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

but I get this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Assertion failed:
../…/rendering/box.dart:1930
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#0992d relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT"

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib/screen_utama.dart:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

list of `data` that I used is data from api... but when I change the data become this one, that doesn't show the error:

```
List data=List.generate(10, (index) => {"id": index, "name": "Lowongan $index"})
      .toList();
```

is There a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In think this happens when your data is empty. You can simply fix it by showing an empty placeholder when no data is available.

For your `Konten` widget the `build` function could look like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (data.isEmpty){
      return Text('no content available');
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: GridView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 1, crossAxisSpacing: 16, mainAxisSpacing: 16, childAspectRatio: 10, mainAxisExtent: 0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(data[index]["API"]),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have checked it just know, yeaah that's because of the data is empty.. thank you very much for your help